# PHP NOTICE:Undefined offset 1

Tags: php

I am facing a problem that undefined offset :1. I can't understand that what type of error it is. Can anyone tell me that why such error occurs in php

```
   <?php
 $host="localhost";
        $dbusername="root";
        $dbpassword="";
        $dbname="school";
        $conn=mysql_connect($host,$dbusername,$dbpassword) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$cls=$_POST['hhcls'];


{

    {

        {
            $query=mysql_query("select * from stu_class where class='$cls'",$conn);
            while($data=mysql_fetch_row($query))
            {
                $r1=$data[0];
                $r=$_POST[$r1]; //THIS LNE ERROR
                echo $r;
                $query1="update stu_class set rollno=".$r." where ad_no=".$r;
                $sql_query1=mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
                if($sql_query1)
                {
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Students Details Updated Successfully');</script>"; 
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Updation Failed');</script>"; 
                }


            }           

        }

    }
}

  }
  ?>
```

I am getting error while passing data to another query

Comment: You should learn how to cleanly format your code.  Also, undefined offset means that the offset specified to an array doesn't exist or is too large.  Most likely the `$r=$_POST[$r1];` line.

Comment: Ok Sir, Thanks. then the Solution Sir???

Comment: @NagaRaj check the line with $query, I think which your $cls variable is wrong implementing

Comment: I check with echo. It returns the expected Value Sir

Comment: what kind of error??

Answer (score 0):

Of course )

Look:

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from stu_class where class='$cls'", $conn);
// Now we got not query, but result of this query in $query

while ($data = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
// Every iteration we will have in $data array (not associated) 
// of fields (next row from database)

$r1 = $data[0];
// After this line we have value of first column of current line in $r1
// usually this is integer ID field and if first ID in database is 1,
// then $r1 = 1

$r = $_POST[$r1]; //THIS LNE ERROR
// here you trying to set $r = $_POST[1] because $r1 = 1
// but you have no any POST variable with key 1.
```

When you trying to get some array member that doesn't exist, you will get notice "Undefined offset %key%". In strict mode you will get exception.